# Javascript Calculator that will break down years to hours days minutes seconds

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a question on as why my code won't execute correctly, I need to be as basic as possible when applying these commands. I hit the convert button and nothing, did I need a command for that too? It is for homework, I have been dabbling at it for hours.

EDIT***

```
  <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
function Convert()
onclick= document.getElementById('Convert')

    var years = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var days = document.getElementById("days").365.25 * years;
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours").(365.25 * 24) * years;
    var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").(365.25 * 24 * 60) * years;
    var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds").(365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60) * years;

document.getElementById('days').value = days;
document.getElementById('hours').value = hours;
document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds;



});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Years: <input type='text' id='years' /> 
    <button id='Convert'onclick= "Convert()" value= "Convert"/> Convert </button>

    Days: <input type='text' id='days' /> 
    Hours: <input type='text' id='hours' /> 
    Minutes: <input type='text' id='minutes' /> 
    Seconds: <input type='text' id='seconds' /> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: These will be hypothetical times then? In reality, years don't have exactly 365 days all the time, nor do days last 24 hours exactly etc.

Comment: There is quite a bit wrong with your code, showing some pretty fundamental confusion about how JavaScript and HTML work.  I think you should do a little more research and review some online tutorials or examples of how to use buttons, prompts, and display data/manipulate DOM elements.

Comment: you're not doing any math, you're not actually calling your `MathThing()` function, your button has no event handlers attached to it. in short, all you're doing is displaying some html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things (hopefully they get you going again):

1. You never call your function. Add an `onClick` handler to your button.
2. You are `prompt` ing fixed strings instead of variables.
3. You'll have to extract the data from the `input` in your JavaScript. You could use `document.getElementById()` for that.

Note, I could give you the answer, but homework and learning is all about figuring stuff out by yourself. Get going with my tips and see what you can come up with. Edit your question with what you got if you get stuck again.

Okay, next round. What you'll have to do in your `Convert` function:

1. First, fetch the information from the form like this:

   ```
    var years = document.getElementById("year").value;
   ```
2. Then, do you calculations:

   ```
    var days = 365 * years;
   ```
3. Finally, write back the results:

   ```
   document.getElementById("days").value = days;
   ```

Some extra tips:

1. You are missing a space between `id='Convert'` and `onclick`
2. Install a debugger like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox.

Good luck!

Round three; here is the complete answer. Just try to understand what is going on. It is usually good to learn from working examples.

Extra stuff I found:

1. An extra `<script>` tag in your html
2. The function definition is wrong, it should be `function foo() {  }`

------ complete answer follows -----

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Declare a function called Convert()
function Convert() {
    // Get the value of what the user entered in "years"
    var years = document.getElementById("years").value;

    // Calculate all the other values
    var days = years * 365.25;
    var hours = days * 24;
    var minutes = hours * 60;
    var seconds = minutes * 60;

    // Write the results in the input fields    
    document.getElementById('days').value = days;
    document.getElementById('hours').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('minutes').value = minutes;
    document.getElementById('seconds').value = seconds;
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    Years: <input type='text' id='years' /> 
    <!-- define a button that will call Convert() when clicked on -->
    <button id='Convert' onclick= "Convert()" value="Convert">Convert</button>

    Days: <input type='text' id='days' /> 
    Hours: <input type='text' id='hours' /> 
    Minutes: <input type='text' id='minutes' /> 
    Seconds: <input type='text' id='seconds' /> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Now for me to create an input you want me to use the getElement for each field function? @bartfriederichs

Comment: Still no execution, I feel like im missing an command to find the result of the function.

Comment: LOL i think i am not getting it :\ @BartFriederichs , just edited my new command.

Comment: Fix the space in your `<button>`.... and then some. I put the solution in my answer.

Comment: Still not seeing why it doesnt calculate :\ @BartFriederichs

Comment: The entire (tested and working) code is in my answer now. Try to find the differences and understand what is going on.